# Cmake: how to choose C++ headers

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, cmake, clang

I want to choose between using `gcc` and `clang` and also want to choose between `libstdc++` and `libc++`. [This site](http://www.omniprog.info/clang_no_gcc.html) explains how to mix compilers and standard libraries. I can choose between compilers by calling `cmake` like `CC=gcc CCX=g++ cmake...` or with `CC=clang...`.

The problem is that with `libstdc++` I need to use the flag `-I/usr/include/c++/5` and with `libc++` the `-I/usr/include/c++/v1`.

For portability reasons I do not want to include the above paths neither in `CMakeListst.txt`, neither as a command line argument. Is there a way to do this and let `cmake` autodetect it?

Comment: Do you mean when you run cmake, you want to select a compiler(gcc/clang) and c++ standard library(libstdc++/libc++). So, do you need camke script, such as `if( clang )...else if( gcc )`?

Comment: @CodeDreamer, I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you already know this, `find_package` boost or openssl are also see certain environment variable such as `BOOST_ROOT` and `OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR`. So you need such hint variable also.

Like [cpprestsdk cmake script](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/blob/master/Release/CMakeLists.txt),

I think your `CMakeLists.txt` is

```
if(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  message("-- Setting clang option")
  include_directories(${Your_path})
  ...

elseif(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "GNU")
  message("-- Setting gcc options")
  include_directories(${Your_path})

  ...

else()
  message("-- Unknown compiler, success is doubtful.")
  message("CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID=${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}")
endif()
```

Comment: Thank you. I hoped the paths are detected automatically and buried in some CMake variables.